# Replace specific character inbetween brackets

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to replace `,` with `:`character that is located in between `[]`. 
So `[Hello, as] a, booby` will change to `[Hello: as] a, booby`. I cannot figure out how to match the comma within brackets, I can match the word inside brackets with 
`\[(.*)\]` but I don't know how to pick the comma from there.

Also if I get `[[Hello, as] a, booby]`, then I also want to change only the first comma. I tried to use `*` or `+` but it doesn't work.

I need this

```
[["Sender", "mail@text.org"], ["Date", "Fri, 09 Jun 2017 13:29:22 +0000"]]
```

To became this

```
[["Sender": "mail@text.org"], ["Date": "Fri, 09 Jun 2017 13:29:22 +0000"]]
```

I wanted to use preg_replace but I It was not the right solution.

```
preg_replace("/(\[[^],]*),/U" , ':', $arr)
```

returns

```
": mail@text.org"], : "Fri, 09 Jun 2017 13:29:22 +0000"]
```

Comment: What are you using? Can you use e.g lookaheads/lookbehinds? What about using capture-groups in the replacement-string?

Comment: The answer that was here worked perfectly `'\[.*?(,).*?\]'` . I tried to use lookbehinds and also capture groups, but with no success.

Comment: Try [`(\[[^],]*),`](https://regex101.com/r/S4bJog/3) to replace with `$1:`.

Comment: Could there be more than one comma in the brackets?

Comment: I think there shouldn't be more than one comma

Comment: `'\[.*?(,).*?\]'` does not work perfectly, it will match [like this](https://regex101.com/r/GVBGh2/1). Could you please add *exact* requirements into the question?

Comment: Oh I see, and I also see that using preg_replace that I wanted to use is not a good solution, I edited OP with what happens.

Comment: @rtom: You used `:` in the replacement. I wrote *to replace with `$1:`*. See https://regex101.com/r/S4bJog/4. Certainly you may also try `'~\[[^],]*\K,~'` and replace with `:` (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/S4bJog/5)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems as simple as I can make it: ([Demo Link](https://regex101.com/r/RMT57z/3))

```
(?<="),
```

It makes some assumptions about your nested psuedo array values.

PHP Implementation:

```
$in='[["Sender", "mail@text.org"], ["Date", "Fri, 09 Jun 2017 13:29:22 +0000"], ["Name", "Dude"]]';
echo preg_replace('/(?<="),/',':',$in);
```

Output:

```
[["Sender": "mail@text.org"], ["Date": "Fri, 09 Jun 2017 13:29:22 +0000"], ["Name": "Dude"]]
```

If this doesn't suit your actual strings, please provide a string where my pattern fails, so that I can adjust it.  Extending the pattern to ensure that that comma follows the quoted "key" can be done like this: `"[^"]+"\K,` ...at a slightly higher step cost (but still not bad).

Answer (score 0):

Try grouping everything before and after the comma, then put them back around the colon.

```
preg_replace('/(\[.*?),(.*?\])/','$1:$2',$string)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `\G` based pattern:

```
$str = preg_replace('~(?:\G(?!\A)|\[(?=[^][]*]))[^][,]*\K,~', ':', $str);
```

This kind of pattern starts with 2 subpatterns in an alternation:

- `\[(?=[^][]*])` that searches a `[` followed by a `]` without other brackets between them.
- `\G(?!\A)` that matches at the position after a previous match

Then, in the two cases `[^][,]*\K,` reaches the next `,` that can only be between `[` and `]`.

But since you also need to skip commas between double quotes, you have to match double quotes parts before an eventual comma. To do that, change `[^][,]*` to `[^][",]*(?:"[^"\\]*(?s:\\.[^"\\]*)*"[^][",]*)*+`

```
$str = preg_replace('~(?:\G(?!\A)|\[(?=[^][]*]))[^][",]*+(?:"[^"\\\\]*(?s:\\\\.[^"\\\\]*)*"[^][",]*)*+\K,~', ':', $str);
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/PL8pVQ/1)